# Weird dotted pattern in fluid simulation

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I tried to simulate honey spilled from a bucket.

The problem is that there is a dotted pattern on the simulation. What is causing this and how to fix it?

The result:

[image: image3]
[image: image1]

My settings:

[image: image2]